# Python with Blender: Using EnumProperty the dynamic way

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I want to use the `EnumProperty` the dynamic way. I've got two dialog boxes. In the first one I'm asking for database parameters and in the second one the user has to choose between some options using a dropdown. It works with a static select `EnumProperty`, but not with a dynamic one.

Here are my two boxes:

```
class IMPORT_DATABASE(Operator):

    bl_idname = "importgis.database"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import.shapefile is constructed (allows calling operator from python console or another script)
    # bl_idname rules: must contain one '.' (dot) charactere, no capital letters, no reserved words (like 'import')
    bl_description = 'Import data from postgis database'
    bl_label = "Import database"

    host = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Host:", default="localhost")
    port = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Port:", default="5432")
    database = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Database:", default="scans")
    user = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Username:",default="postgres")
    password = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Password:",default="postgres")

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.importgis.database_connection('INVOKE_DEFAULT', password=self.password, username=self.user, database=self.database, port=self.port, host=self.host)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

And the second dialog box:

```
class IMPORT_DATABASE_CONNECTION(Operator):
    bl_idname = "importgis.database_connection"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import.shapefile is constructed (allows calling operator from python console or another script)
    # bl_idname rules: must contain one '.' (dot) charactere, no capital letters, no reserved words (like 'import')
    bl_description = 'Geometry'
    bl_label = "Geometry"

    host = StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    port = StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    database = StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    username = StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    password = StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})

    num = EnumProperty(
        items=get_items(),
        name="Geometry",
        description="choose a geometry",
        default=None,
        options={'ANIMATABLE'},
        update=None,
        get=None,
        set=None)



    def get_items(self):
        # condata = "dbname='%s' user='%s' host='%s' password='%s'" % \
        #          (self.database, self.user, self.host, self.password)
        # try:
        #    conn = psycopg2.connect(condata)
        # except:
        #    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")
        # cur = conn.cursor()
        # cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM public.geometry_columns""")
        # rows = cur.fetchall()
        # items = []
        # for row in rows:
        # geomItems = geomItems+row[0]+"//"+row[1]+"//"+row[2]+"#"
        # geomItems = geomItems + row[0] + "#"
        # items.append(row[0],row[1],row[2])

        items = [
            ('NONE', 'None', "Flat geometry"),
            ('GEOM', 'Geometry', "Use z value from shape geometry if exists"),
            ('FIELD', 'Field', "Extract z elevation value from an attribute field"),
            ('OBJ', 'Object', "Get z elevation value from an existing ground mesh")
        ]
        return items

    def execute(self, context):
        message = "Connection"
        self.report({'INFO'}, message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("Invoke")
        self.pretty_print()
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

Maybe I can't find a way to build the select options in this way. I still get this error:

> File "C:\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 331, in enable
>       mod = **import**(module_name)
>     File "C:\Users\R62ad002\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master__init__.py", line 45, in 
>       from .operators import * #see operators/**init**/**all**
>     File "C:\Users\R62ad002\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\operators\io_import_database.py", line 74, in 
>       class IMPORT_DATABASE_CONNECTION(Operator):
>     File "C:\Users\R62ad002\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\operators\io_import_database.py", line 86, in IMPORT_DATABASE_CONNECTION
>       num = EnumProperty(items=get_items, name="Geometry")
>   NameError: name 'get_items' is not defined

Can someone help me?

Comment: Couple of things from quick look.  The items callback needs two arguments, `get_items(self, context)`   where `self` is the object the enum is on (the operator in this case).  Should be an error message to explain such.   For the commented part if cant connect to server still need to return a list.

Comment: I´ve changed the  `def get_items(self):` to `def get_items(self, context):`, but i still get the same error: `NameError: name 'get_items' is not defined`

Comment: `num = EnumProperty(items=get_items, name="Blah")`  Pass the method not the return value. for a dynamic property. [See docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example).

Comment: i get the same error by changing to `EnumProperty(items=get_items...`

Comment: Note that you have to keep a reference to the enum items, otherwise you can get weird behaviour in Blender (even crashes). See the red box here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=enumproperty#bpy.props.EnumProperty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Fixes to question code.**

- define items as a method `items=get_items`, not what is returned
  `items=get_items()`  [See Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty)
- The items method requires two arguments `self` and `context`
- Ensure the items method is defined before assigning argment to it Not doing so will result in

  > `NameError: name 'get_items' is not defined`

Code

EDIT Update for 2.8.  For prior see [revisions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/122595/5)

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, EnumProperty

class ImportDataBaseConnection(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "importgis.database_connection" 
    bl_description = 'Import Geometry Data'
    bl_label = "Geometry"

    host : StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    port : StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    database : StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    username : StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    password : StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})

    def item_callback(self, context):
        return (
            ('NONE', 'None', "Flat geometry"),
            ('GEOM', 'Geometry', "Use z value from shape geometry if exists"),
            ('FIELD', 'Field', "Extract z elevation value from an attribute field"),
            ('OBJ', 'Object', "Get z elevation value from an existing ground mesh"),
        )

    geo_type : EnumProperty(
        items=item_callback,
        name="Geometry Type",
        description="choose a geometry",
        default=None,
        options={'ANIMATABLE'},
        update=None,
        get=None,
        set=None)

    def execute(self, context):
        message = "Connection"
        self.report({'INFO'}, message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=500)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImportDataBaseConnection)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImportDataBaseConnection)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.importgis.database_connection('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Made a minimal working example, run in test editor, pops up dialog with enum items from the update method.

Comment: Thanks for akk this great help. These examples solve my problems.